# Does an allocator.construct loop equal std::uninitialized_copy?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

In this context `T` is  a certain type and `allocator` is an allocator object for that type. By default it is `std::allocator<T>` but this is not necessarily true.

I have a chunk of memory acquired by `allocator.allocate(n)`. I also have a container `con` of `T` objects (say, a `std::vector<T>`). I want to initialize that chunk of memory with the `T` object(s).

The location of the chunk of memory is stored in `T* data`.

Are these two code examples always identical?

```
#include <memory>

// example 1
std::uninitialized_copy(con.begin(), con.end(), data)

// example 2
std::vector<T>::const_iterator in = con.begin();
for (T* out = data; in != con.end(); ++out, ++in) {
    allocator.construct(out, *in);
}
```

And for these two?

```
#include <memory>

T val = T(); // could be any T value

// example 3
std::uninitialized_fill(data, data + n, val)

// example 4
for (T* out = data; out != (data + n); ++out) {
    allocator.construct(out, val);
}
```

Comment: I think allocator.address takes an object (or reference to one) as parameter (the std::allocator just performs &x). It does not return the last allocated address, as you seem to assume.

Comment: @Christian Rau: Woops, let me edit according to my code.

Comment: When you say identical, do you mean with regards to the memory allocated and initialized, or with regards to performance, or something else entirely?

Comment: @steveo225: I mean __exactly__ the same memory allocated and initialized and the same "execution path", so with the same copy constructor's, initializers, etc. Performance is relevant, but irrelevant for now (sounds weird, but true).

Comment: Should not 'in' be ++ed in the first example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this explanations](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/memory/) They should do the same, as `allocator::construct` is said to construct the object and `std::uninitialized...` also constructs the objects. But I do not know, what exactly the standard says and what freedom you have, when implementing your own `allocator::construct`.

**EDIT:** Ok, the C++03 standard states in section 20.1.5 §2 table 32, that `construct(p,t)` should have the same effect as `new ((void*)p) T(t)` (for any standard compliant allocator, not only `std::allocator`). And in 20.4.4.1 §1, that `uninitialized_copy` should have the same effect as

```
for (; first != last; ++result, ++first)
    new (static_cast<void*>(&*result))
            typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type(*first);
```

and in 20.4.4.2 §1, that `uninitialized_fill` has an effect of

```
for (; first != last; ++first)
    new (static_cast<void*>(&*first))
            typename iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type(x);
```

So I think that doesn't leave any room for them to behave differently. So to answer your question: yes, it does.

Comment: Yeah, I got this far too, but I want it more precise, preferably with quotes from the standard. I am making a container myself and this can be very critical. In such cases I try to stay away from cppreference as far as possible.

Comment: @nightcracker Ok, proved it with standard reference.

Answer (score 0):

*C++ Primer 5th* §13.6.2:

> .....
>   `uninitialized_copy` calls `construct` on each element in the input
>   sequence to “copy” that element into the destination. That algorithm
>   uses the iterator dereference operator to fetch elements from the
>   input sequence. Because we passed move iterators, the dereference
>   operator yields an rvalue reference, which means `construct` will use
>   the move constructor to construct the elements.
>   .....