# C++ Calling allocator.construct for Primitives

Tags: c++, memory-management, allocator

Is it necessary for me to call allocator.construct() for an array of primitive types allocated using an arbitrary allocator, as in the code listing below? The class doesn't require the allocated memory to be initialized to any particular value, so it seems to me that calling allocator.construct() with a newly-allocated chunk of memory would be unnecessary. Is there any danger in not calling this method, given that the array always consists of primitive types?

```
template <class T, template <class> class Allocator = std::allocator>
class foo
{
public:
    typedef Allocator<T> allocator;
    typedef typename allocator::pointer pointer;
private:
    unsigned size_;
    allocator alloc_;
    pointer t_;
public:
    foo(unsigned n) throw(std::bad_alloc) : size_(n), alloc_(),
    t_(alloc_.allocate(n))
    {
        // Note that I do not call alloc_.construct() here.
    }

    ~foo() { alloc_.deallocate(t_, size_); }
};
```

Comment: Rather than trying to describe your code, it may be easier to simply post some simple illustrative code.

Comment: I added a code sample to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The allocator is free to impose whatever custom book-keeping it wants, including the number of existing objects. There is no guarantee at all that it simply does `new (memory) T(...)`. And in addition, it would be a very nasty surprise for a person to change your code so that it's no longer just primitives and then find it randomly breaks sometime later.

Comment: Also, is it safe to allocate the memory using allocate() and then initialize it using uninitialized_copy()?

Comment: For those who may be curious, I think this link answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047840/does-an-allocator-construct-loop-equal-stduninitialized-copy. It is safe to use uninitialized_copy to initialize memory returned by allocator.allocate().